# Identifying robots

Tags: asp.net, iis, web, robots.txt

We are having an issue where robots are hitting our site and maxing out CPU usage. It's an ASP.NET Web Forms based site, we need to be able to identify these automatically and capture the IP addresses and write them to an event log, we can't put it in a database because of speed issues. Is this possible? Has anyone ever accomplished something like this? I have manually done this before but it's not possible with all the traffic we see to do this anymore.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it an IIS server? If so, google on something like "iis log analyzer bot" should help.

Comment: This sounds like a very broad description of the problem. Can you give some more details about the problems you are facing with various solutions like the database? Or how much load you have on that server/s? Your problem sounds much more like a performance problem than a robots problem. What do you want to do this those IP addresses at the end?

Comment: @mickey please try to suggest more substantive edits than fixing a single letter typo.

Comment: @mickey yes its IIS. Our idea is to have a "bot" web server that we kick these IP addresses to. It's not a performance issue, we are seeing a 90% CPU load with these requests.

Comment: Related post : http://moz.com/ugc/blocking-bots-based-on-useragent